# REM function in remind for timed reminders over a specific interval

Tags: calendar, reminder

I am trying to write a linux [remind](http://www.roaringpenguin.com/products/remind) script that has reminders for things I have to review on a certain time interval. Let's say this is: 1 month, 3 months, 1 year, 3 years. The trick is that I need each reminder to only go once. Can anyone help me with this?

Something along the lines of:

```
REM $Sys.date * 31 ONCE MSG Review that thing
REM $Sys.date * 62 ONCE MSG Review that thing
REM $Sys.date * 365 ONCE MSG Review that thing
REM $Sys.date * 1095 ONCE MSG Review that thing
```

Thanks.

Comment: Some more context like the operating system and the scripting language you're using would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was advised on the Remind mailing list that this is a tricky thing to do. It's best just to make 5  separate reminders:

```
REM July 4 2013 MSG Review
REM August 4 2013 MSG Review
REM November 4 2013 MSG Review
REM July 4 2014 MSG Review
REM July 4 2016 MSG Review
```

If someone figures out a way to do this within the Remind scripting language, let me know.

Thanks.